# Powershell "looking for visual studio 2017, failed to find a suitable Visual Studio installation."

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to use a .\vcbuild test before contributing to an open source project.  When I'm in powershell I try to run the test and it shows "looking for python 2.x" "looking for NASM" "looking for visual studio 2017" and then gives me the error -

"looking for visual studio 2017, failed to find a suitable Visual Studio installation. Try to run in a "Developer Command Prompt."  I have tried it in Git Bash, and even the Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt.  I have Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 installed, 2017 I have the Visual C++ tools and the Visual Studio Build Tools.  Why is it unable to find this?  Is there a way to use the vswhere.exe file to fix this?

Comment: What kind of open source project? It is strange to require VCBuild, while MSBuild is used to build C++ projects for so long a time.

Comment: It is for node.js contributions.   Maybe MSBuild has superceded it? / is the better way to go?